# Crystal Report Not Working When I upload it to the web server in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Crystal Report is working in local host but it is not working when I upload it to the web server.

Any one have idea about it Why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have crystal report DLL-s also on server side.